# Visual studio codemap generation doesn't work for my DLLs, and show as an error level "NoResult"

Tags: visual-studio, class-diagram

So I've been trying out the visual studio enterprise tool CodeMap for the codebase of my company, and it seems to compile fine, but when I get to the codemap, it just shows the dll name, but I cannot expand the graph.

Is there any way to see why the graph can't show result? Any way to look at logs of the graph generation?

Normally, I should be able to expand, and see all the relations between classes, namespace, etc... It seems I have an error level of NoResult, but no information as to why there is no result.

[image: code map failed][image]

Thanks